# For $P$ an arbitrary point in $\triangle ABC$, show that $\sum_{cyc}c(\sin \angle CAP+\sin\angle CBP)\leq a+b+c$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

> In the interior of $\triangle ABC$ we take the arbitrary point $P$. Prove that the following inequality holds: $$\small c(\sin\angle CAP + \sin\angle CBP) + a(\sin\angle ABP +\sin\angle ACP) + b(\sin\angle BCP + \sin\angle BAP)\\ \le a + b + c$$

I tried to draw the distances from $P$ to the sides of the triangle and write the sines from the right angled triangles, but I couldn't get anything out of it. I saw that a case of equality is when the triangle is equilateral and $P$ is its center.

Can you help me?

Comment: Interesting inequality. Where does it come from?

Comment: It is from the romanian publishment “Gazeta Matematica”.

Comment: If you would be as kind as to tell us what edition of the Gazette that might be, we might be able to look things up ;)

Comment: It is from the edition 10/2018, the number of the problem being S:L18.249 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify derivation introduce the notation:
$$
BC=a,\quad AC=b,\quad AB=c,\\
\measuredangle{CAB}=\alpha,\quad 
\measuredangle{ABC}=\beta,\quad 
\measuredangle{BCA}=\gamma;\\
\measuredangle{ABP}=\alpha_B,\quad
\measuredangle{ACP}=\alpha_C,\\
\measuredangle{BAP}=\beta_A,\quad
\measuredangle{BCP}=\beta_C,\\\
\measuredangle{CAP}=\gamma_A,\quad
\measuredangle{CBP}=\gamma_B.
$$
Then the initial inequality can be written as:
$$\small
\frac{a(\sin\alpha_B+\sin\alpha_C)
+b(\sin\beta_A+\sin\beta_C)+c(\sin\gamma_A+\sin\gamma_B)}{a+b+c}\le1.\tag{*}
$$
which can be proved as follows:
$$\begin{align}\small
&\scriptsize\frac{a(\sin\alpha_B+\sin\alpha_C)
+b(\sin\beta_A+\sin\beta_C)+c(\sin\gamma_A+\sin\gamma_B)}{a+b+c}\\
&\scriptsize=\frac{\sin\alpha(\sin\alpha_B+\sin\alpha_C)
+\sin\beta(\sin\beta_A+\sin\beta_C)+\sin\gamma(\sin\gamma_A+\sin\gamma_B)}
{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma}\tag1\\
&\scriptsize=\frac{(\sin\beta\sin\beta_A+\sin\gamma\sin\gamma_A)
+(\sin\alpha\sin\alpha_B+\sin\gamma\sin\gamma_B)
+(\sin\alpha\sin\alpha_C+\sin\beta\sin\beta_C)}
{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma}\tag2\\
&\scriptsize\le\frac{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma}{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma}=1\tag3.
\end{align}
$$

> Explanation:
>
> (1)
>   Substitution: 
>   $$a=2R\sin\alpha, \quad b=2R\sin\beta, \quad c=2R\sin\gamma.$$
>
> (2)
>   Rearrangement.
>
> (3) Transformation of sine products to cosine differences and then from cosine sums to cosine products:
>   $$\begin{align}
> &\scriptsize\sin\beta\sin\beta_A+\sin\gamma\sin\gamma_A\\
> &\scriptsize=\frac{\cos(\beta-\beta_A)-\cos(\beta+\beta_A)}2
> +\frac{\cos(\gamma-\gamma_A)-\cos(\gamma+\gamma_A)}2\\
> &\scriptsize=\frac{\cos(\beta-\beta_A)+\cos(\gamma-\gamma_A)}2
> -\frac{\cos(\beta+\beta_A)+\cos(\gamma+\gamma_A)}2\\
> &\scriptsize=
> \underbrace{\cos\frac{\beta+\gamma-\beta_A-\gamma_A}2}_{\ge0}
> \underbrace{\cos\frac{\beta-\gamma-\beta_A+\gamma_A}2}_{\le1}
> -
> \underbrace{\cos\frac{\beta+\gamma+\beta_A+\gamma_A}2}_{=0}\cos\frac{\beta-\gamma+\beta_A-\gamma_A}2\tag4\\
> &\scriptsize\le \cos\frac{\beta+\gamma-\alpha}2=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-\alpha\right)=\sin\alpha,
> \end{align}
> $$
>   where we used $\beta_A+\gamma_A=\alpha$.

---

There may arise an interesting question when does the inequality $(\text{*})$ degenerate to equality?

It is easily seen from $(4)$ that this happens if and only if the following equations hold:
$$
\begin {cases}
\beta-\beta_A=\gamma-\gamma_A\\
\gamma-\gamma_B=\alpha-\alpha_B\\
\alpha-\alpha_C=\beta-\beta_C
\end {cases},
$$
which together with
$$
\begin {cases}
\beta_A+\gamma_A=\alpha\\
\gamma_B+\alpha_B=\beta\\
\alpha_C+\beta_C=\gamma
\end {cases}
$$
implies:
$$
\begin {cases}
\beta_C=\gamma_B=\frac\pi2-\alpha\\
\gamma_A=\alpha_C=\frac\pi2-\beta\\
\alpha_B=\beta_A=\frac\pi2-\gamma
\end {cases}.
$$

Thus the equality holds if and only if the triangle $ABC$ is acute and $P$ is its circumcenter.

Note:

With the convention that the angle measures at a triangle vertex are signed and the direction towards the adjacent side is positive, the inequality (*) becomes valid for the whole plane. Correspondingly it degenerates to equality at the circumcenter of the triangle, regardless of its shape.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @MichaelGoldberg You're welcome!

Comment: Great presentation!

Comment: @Allawonder Thank you!

Comment: A lovely solution! Just one remark though: the case of equality entails indeed the equations displayed in the final curly brace, however the conclusion on $P$ is not entirely correct. From $\sphericalangle{ABP}=\sphericalangle{BAP}$ one infers $|PA|=|PB|$ and the analogues, to the conclusion that $P$ is the **circumcenter**. The requirement that the triangle be acute is indeed valid.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Thank you for catching the typo. Corrected.